# Does str type use ASCII encoder/decoder?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

On Python 2 REPL:

```
>>> sys.stdin.encoding 
'UTF-8'
```

So my understanding is, on giving the below expression on `stdin`

```
>>> stringLiteral = 'abc'
```

the interpreter reads the expression from `stdin` in `utf-8` encoding and interprets the code.

But I learnt that, in Python 2, `str` type stores `'abc'` as a byte string, and internally in CPython it's stored as a C `char *` null-terminated string (i.e. an array of bytes terminated by `\0`).

What encoding scheme does the `str` class use to store `'abc'` in memory? What decoding scheme does `str` use to print `'abc'` on printing it?

Based on the answer, If I give the below expression:

```
>>> stringLiteralNonAsciiRange = 'abc정정'
```

then why does `stringLiteralNonAsciiRange` not print `정정`? Why is the output `'abc\xec\xa0\x95\xec\xa0\x95\xf0\x9f\x92\x9b'`?

Comment: Python 2 interprets string literals as `ASCII` bytes. `sys.stdin.encoding` is irrelevant, since a literal is not taken from `stdin`

Comment: 1. ASCII by default, unless you specify unicode (the `u` prepended to the string will be an indicator). 2. Try `print repr(stringLiteralNonAsciiRange)`.

Comment: I'll take "why python 3 is better" for 400, Alex. ;)

Comment: In other words, Python 2 `str` == Python 3 `bytes`.

Comment: Just typing the name of a variable is NOT the same as printing it - it's more like `print repr(variable)`.  The `repr` of a string uses escape sequences for all non-ASCII and non-printable characters, so that you can see exactly what's in the string.

Comment: @erip My understanding is, python 3's `bytes` type memory representation should be simialr to python 2's `str` type

Comment: Sure. You'll need to decode those bytes as unicode.

Comment: You'll also note `'\xec\xa0\x95\xec\xa0\x95\xf0\x9f\x92\x9b'.decode('utf8')` gives `u'\uc815\uc815\U0001f49b'` which *is* `"정정"`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why `abc정정'.decode('utf-8')` gives
`u'abc\uc815\uc815\U0001f49b'` but not `abc정정`? which is still not clear to me.

Comment: There's a [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) between an object's `__repr__` method and an object's `__str__` method.

Comment: @eriq OK. So, `decode()` output  in my previous comment has nothing to do with encoding/decoding. Thankyou

Comment: @Shiva  Is ascii decoder used in both cases? `print repr(stringLiteral)` and `print repr(stringLiteralNonAsciiRange)`, as they are byte strings and nothing more than that

Comment: Yes, in the latter case, ASCII doesn't recognise those characters, so it is printed as is (`abc\xec\xa0\x95\xec\xa0\x95\xf0\x9f\x92\x9b`).

Comment: @Shiva If it was ascii encoding scheme used to store `stringLiteralNonAsciiRange`, then `stringLiteralNonAsciiRange.decode('ascii')` should not fail. But it fails. So it contradicts here.